# ¿Es necesario guardar la ruta de la imagen en la Bd para mostrar cada imagen con su respectivo id?

Tags: php, mysqli

Actualmente tengo un código que extrae la ultima ruta de modificación de imagen de cada usuario, esto extraído desde una carpeta y una subcarpeta creada con el id de cada usuario(files/id/imagen.jpg). No guardo la ultima ruta en la Bd.

Este es es el código:

```
                                    /* el id especifica de que usuario quieres mostrar la imagen*/   
                                           $id = 11;
                                            $path = "files/".$id;
                                                if(file_exists($path)){
                                              $directorio = opendir($path);
                                                 while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)){
                                                if (!is_dir($archivo)):
                                                      $archivos[filemtime($path.'/'.$archivo)] = $path.'/'.$archivo;
                                                  endif;
                                                }
                                                  closedir($directorio);

                                                     //Ordenar el array
                                                     ksort($archivos);

                                                     //Buscar la última modificacida
                                                     $ultimaModificada = end($archivos);

                                                 //Compara todas las URLs y solo muestra la última modificada
                                                 foreach ($archivos as $archivo){

                                             if ($archivo == $ultimaModificada){?>
                                                  <div data="<?php echo $path; ?>-<?php echo $archivo; ?>">

                                                 </div>
                                                 <img src="<?php echo utf8_encode($archivo); ?>" width='200' height='200' 'image-align:center' />


                                                    <?php
                                                 }
                                                }   
                                          } 

                            ?>
```

Este código solo te muestra la imagen de un único usuario y yo quiero que me muestre todas las imágenes que tengo en raíz(files/id) por cada usuario por id en una tabla.

Algo así:

```
                         require 'enlace.php';
                        $id = $_GET['id'];
                        $sql = "SELECT id FROM personas";
                        $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
                         $row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); 




<div class="container">
    <div class="row table-responsive">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr class = "warning">
                        <th>Foto</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLASSOC))
                    { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td> <div class="main">





            <form id="uploadimage" style="text-align:center" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <td>  $id = isset($_POST['id']);
                                            $path = "files/".$id;
                                                if(file_exists($path)){
                                              $directorio = opendir($path);
                                                 while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)){
                                                if (!is_dir($archivo)):
                                                      $archivos[filemtime($path.'/'.$archivo)] = $path.'/'.$archivo;
                                                  endif;
                                                }
                                                  closedir($directorio);

                                                     //Ordenar el array
                                                     ksort($archivos);

                                                     //Buscar la última modificacida
                                                     $ultimaModificada = end($archivos);

                                                 //Compara todas las URLs y solo muestra la última modificada
                                                 foreach ($archivos as $archivo){

                                             if ($archivo == $ultimaModificada){?>
                                                  <div data="<?php echo $path; ?>-<?php echo $archivo; ?>">

                                                 </div>
                                                 <img src="<?php echo utf8_encode($archivo); ?>" width='200' height='200' 'image-align:center' />


                                                    <?php
                                                 }
                                                }   
                                          } 

                            ?> </td>

                </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
```

El problema esta en el id.

Gracias.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Es porque estás obteniendo el id desde el `$_POST['id']` siendo que deberías estar recorriendo la variable que trae los registros de la base de datos, designada `$row`.

Observa esta sección

`require 'enlace.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT id FROM personas";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Luego más abajo utilizas

`$id = isset($_POST['id']);`